# PHP: Array key-value, how to show value by key?

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
Array
(
    [name1@domain.com] => Array
        (
            [0] => domain.de
            [1] => domain.org
            [2] => domain.eu
        )

    [name2@domain.biz] => Array
        (
            [0] => domain.net
        )

)
```

I want print the content something like this

```
name1@domain.com has domain.de, domain.org, domain.eu
name2@domain.biz has domain.net
```

I used this trick, but it didn't work:

```
foreach($array as $email => $domains){
        foreach($domains as $key => $domain){
        $domener_t[] = $domain;
    }
    $domains = implode(", ",$domener_t);
    echo $email.$domains."<br>";
}
```

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: This question does not show any research effort

Comment: I have tried and searched around. But forgot post my own code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
$MyArray = array('name1@domain.com' => array('domain.de','domain.org','domain.eu'),'name2@domain.biz' => array('domain.net'));

foreach ($MyArray as $key => $value)
{
    echo $key . ' has '. implode(', ', $value).'<br>';
}
?>
```

output

```
name1@domain.com has domain.de, domain.org, domain.eu
name2@domain.biz has domain.net
```

Comment: Hey, just an tip; PHP doesn't display errors but, it's a good pratice when you use keywords in lowercase, e.g: `array()`, not `Array()`

Answer (score 3):

You should use a for-each loop.

```
foreach($array AS $domain => $domains) {
 printf("%s has %s\r\n", $domain, implode(", ", $domains));
}
```